# changing offset dynamically modifies the position of element

Tags: kineticjs

In my program, I placed the rectangle at `[75,75]`, but when I change offset, the rectangle position is getting changed according to offset. I want to avoid it.

Comment: I've modified your question a bit to make it more clear. Please check if this still is what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The offset changes the position. So just do:

```
   rectangle.setOffset(0,0);
```

Comment: please add some more details or a jsfiddle of the exact problem and I can help you out.

Answer (score -1):

Get the absolute position of the shape before changing the offset.

After changing the offset position of the shape, the shape will move to a new location.

Set the absolute position of the shape now to the absolute position before the offset change

```
var currPos = rect.getAbsolutePosition();
rect.setOffset(rect.getWidth()/2,rect.getHeight()/2);
rect.setAbsolutePosition(currPos);
```

this is applicable when the offset changes after the resize of the shape.